# XML message parsing using XSD

Tags: xsd, xml-parsing

An xml message is received through a JMS listener and the message is validated against an XSD. Though the message is valid, at times the message is considered to be invalid and the following exception is raised.

The xml message in not encoded with UTF-8, the message just starts and ends with root.

```
Msg Format :
<root>
<Message>Sample Message</Message>
</root>
```

What could be the issue that is causing the message to be invalidated though it is valid.

Websphere server - 6.1
JDK version 1.6
Spring version - 2.3x

```
Parser Code :

        InputStream inputStream = getResource().getInputStream();
        Source schemaSource = new SAXSource(new InputSource(inputStream));
        Schema schema = getSchemaFactory().newSchema(schemaSource);
        ValidatorHandler validatorHandler = schema.newValidatorHandler();
        validatorHandler.setContentHandler(this);
        parser = getParser();
        parser.setContentHandler(validatorHandler);
                InputStream iStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(asyncMsg.getBytes());
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(iStream);
```

Error logs :

```
Exception 
        at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBWrapper$PriviledgedOnMessage.run(MDBWrapper.java:302)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:192)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:65)
        at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBWrapper.callOnMessage(MDBWrapper.java:271)
        at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:240)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.run(MQSession.java:1695)
        at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSSessionHandle.run(JMSSessionHandle.java:1040)
        at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.connectionConsumerOnMessage(ServerSession.java:1031)
        at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.onMessage(ServerSession.java:711)
        at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.dispatch(ServerSession.java:678)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
        at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSessionDispatcher.dispatch(ServerSessionDispatcher.java:44)
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:100)
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:136)
        at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.run(ServerSession.java:536)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOM.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.SchemaContentHandler.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)

        ... 24 more
```

Comment: That exception isn't complaining about the XML document being invalid, it's failing to load the _schema_ in the first place.

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for the response.

But it fails to load very rarely and not everytime, It's like out of 100 times, this happens only once. I would like to know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you just load the `Schema` object once up front, then reuse it for each parse operation, or is it not thread-safe?

Comment: The schema details are mentioned in the service-beans,xml hence it would be loaded during the JVM start up. Thats why it works fine , but it fails sometimes, not sure of what could be the cause.